# Append input from search box into button link

Tags: php, html, wordpress, button, hyperlink

I'll make this short and quick. :)

I'm trying to implement a button on my website, which redirects me to a URL I specify + what the user is looking for.

I have this little piece of code here:

```
<html>
  <div class="search">
    <form role="search" method="get" id="search">
        <div>
            <input type="text" value="" name="tag_search" id="tag_search" />
            <input type="button" value="Cerca" onclick="window.location.href='https://mywebsite.com/'" />
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</html>
```

that is *almost* working.

The only thing is that if the User inputs "Hello" in the Search Box, it will always search for the following URL once you press the "Submit" button: https://mywebsite.com/

How can I append what the User has written into the Search Box, so that the Button will redirect me to: https://mywebsite.com/Hello ?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the value of the input to the link

```html
<html>
  <div class="search">
    <form role="search" method="get" id="search">
      <div>
        <input type="text" value="" name="tag_search" id="tag_search" />
        <input type="button" value="Cerca" 
          onclick="window.location.href='https://mywebsite.com/' + 
          document.getElementById('tag_search').value" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following Javascript to help

```js
<script>
function goToSearch() {
    window.location.href= 'https://mywebsite.com/' + encodeURI(document.getElementById("tag_search").value)
}

</script>
```

Then your HTML should look like this

```
<html>
  <div class="search">
    <form role="search" method="get" id="search">
        <div>
            <input type="text" value="" name="tag_search" id="tag_search" />
            <input type="button" value="Cerca" onclick="goToSearch()" />
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: @SlimShadys `encodeURI()` is important to ensure the resultant URL is web safe.